# Qual é a diferença entre MD5, SHA e SHA 2 no MYSQL e qual deles é mais recomendado para armazenamento de informação no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql

Costumo armazenar as senhas dos usuários por meio de MD5 no banco de dados. 
Sendo que participo de um grupo, e o pessoal de lá disse que não é recomendado a utilização de MD5 para armazenamento de dados no banco, pois ele pode ser facilmente quebrado. Chegando ao ponto de falarem que utilizar MD5 é a mesma coisa que salvar os dados da forma normal (sem utilizar algo para hash).

Minha dúvida é se é seguro armazenar dados no banco com MD5 e os SHA  (qual deles é a melhor forma) e se existe outra forma mais segura de se criptografar dados. A dúvida se resume a MYSQL. Mas se tiverem alguma colocação de PHP que envolva isso, também seria útil.

Obrigado!

Comment: Nenhum desses é feito para senhas. Você precisa de um KDF, mais especificamente um PBKDF, e não de uma hash. Use o [Argon2](https://password-hashing.net), o PHP suporta nativamente no `password_hash`, existem várias e várias perguntas sobre isso.

Comment: Conforme você pode ver na resposta que foi marcada como duplicada, usar um hash puro para armazenar senha não é muito bom, pois o hash de uma senha fraca provavelmente já consta de uma "tabela arco-íris" e pode ser procurado até no Google (procure por d3b07384d113edec49eaa6238ad5ff00 e você vai encontrar que "foo" é a palavra que originou). O mínimo possível é usar um "tempero" ou "salt" para evitar isso, e o ideal mesmo é usar uma rotina específica para senhas como bcrypt() que evitam outras fraquezas relacionadas a uso de hash puro para ofuscar senhas.

Comment: Muito completa a resposta lá. Realmente é perfeita para o meu caso.